# Cannot deserialize the JSON object into 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' type

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, deserialization, bsondocument

So I have a JSON file that I want to convert to an object that contains a `BsonDocument` but I get an error.

My JSON file is:

```
{
  "words": {
    "wordList": {
      "d": "duck",
      "t": "truck",
      "l": "luck",
      "s": "suck"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to be able to deserialize it by doing this:

```cs
var contentTest = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/TestConfig.json");
var testresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEntity>(contentTest);
```

But I get the following:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' because the type requires a JSON
> array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
> either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
> deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
> primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
> List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'words.wordList.d', line 4,
> position 10.

My class `TestEntity` looks like this:

```cs
public class TestEntity
{
    public IDictionary<string, BsonDocument> Words { get; set; }
}
```

How can I modify my JSON file in order to be able to deserialize those objects into a `BsonDocument`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the serializer/deserializer from *MongoDB.Bson* library instead of *Newtonsoft.Json* library.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

var testresult = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestEntity>(contentTest);
```

```cs
public class TestEntity
{
    [BsonElement("words")]
    public IDictionary<string, BsonDocument> Words { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qib0sV)